# real time view update

Tags: spring-mvc

I plan to develop an admin tool using Spring MVC. One view would show an order update, wherein a user would enter a product code and an update status. For every record in the database that is updated, I want to show in real time the record of the order updated.

What I am unsure is how to display this in the view from controller - would i be using a jquery grid to perform this or is there some feature built in spring mvc

[Read this article](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/13/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application/)  , but seems that may be an overkill for my simple app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is filling out a form in your view (entering the product code and update status) and you want to display the data in that view after they submit (without page reload), you will need to use AJAX. Hook a JavaScript function to an event in your form:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){

   $.ajax("/path/to/controller/route", {

     // Insert various request options...

     data: {
       // data to be sent along with the reqest.
     }

     success: function(data){

        // Define function that is fired when the AJAX request returns successfully.

     }

   });

});
```

This path should hit an endpoint on the server side that will perform the update on your desired record, and can return the info about the record that you desire back to the client side. When the request returns successfully, you can do whatever you want with the data via the success function's `data` argument. You can find more information about the jQuery AJAX functions [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and more about jQuery Events [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

If by "in real time" you mean on a timer, instead of on some user triggered event, the solution is similar, but the AJAX request would be defined in the callback function of `setTimeout()` call or a similarly acting jQuery provided function (such as `delay()`)

Comment: By real time I meant that say there are 100 records to be updated - as some orders are fulfilled by vendor and need to update their records by say a webservice call, so i would be in a loop and update each record and the result of each update is what I would want to show to the user

Comment: So is the view where a "user would enter a product code and an update status" different from the view that you would go to to see your live update? Do you have a way of knowing when a vendor updates one of your records (database trigger, flag, or other service that can notify your server hosting Spring/your code)?

Comment: When vendor updates prices/info we get an email to a specific inbox which is monitored by a process which then feeds into our database. This way when user launches my admin site, they can click on button 'update vendor info' and this will start obtaining all records and then for each order start calling the vendor web service and display result and then move on to next one , till [n]

Comment: It sounds like you have everything you need then. If your database has knowledge of all of the vendor updates (via some update date attribute or flag presumably), then when "update vendor info" is clicked you can query your database to obtain these updated records and display them to the user however you want. Or do you want to set up a continuous loop that monitors these database changes like in a live feed? I guess what I'm asking is, is [n] in your example finite based on a vendor's previous actions, or infinite and being monitored indefinitely?

Comment: My only stumbling block is how do i update the view? I assume this would be via ajax so as i get each result i would update a grid on view so user would know which order got updated. It's the ajax bit that is stumping me. Have to re-read your links.

Comment: If you are calling jQuery's `ajax` function from a script loaded by your view, you can update your view in the `success: function(data){...}` callback. Here, data is the information returned from your server, and you can update whatever you need to how you normally would with jQuery.